# Designing a mains powered device in metal chassis, EMC/EMI/ESD/safety considerations for CE testing

Tags: grounding, safety, emc, esd

I hope this topic is not too broad. I will formulate it as specific as possible.
I have read many articles and guides about EMC testing, but I am still unsure whether I am overlooking something important which could lead to an easily avoidable failure in the expensive testing. Failing the expensive tests could have disastrous effects as we are a small start-up.

I am designing a low powered analog measurement device that will be housed in a painted 2 HU rack metal chassis, of which all parts are joined in a conductive way during assembly. Externally, the device is insulating due to the paintjob.

The device will have a C14 mains power inlet and consume maximum 100 W. Although there will be a wide range commercial AC/DC converter module inside the device, the topic specifically is about european mains and CE related testing. The AC/DC converter is itself CE rated and has a gridded metal frame, that will be bolted to the chassis. The earth wire will be connected to the chassis internally. All touchable conductive parts of connectors will be directly connected to earth ground, too. The live and neutral wires will be connected directly to a rocker switch and the AC/DC converter, but nowhere else. I hope this will be fine for the safety testing and ESD testing.

Signal ground will be isolated from earth, but will be pulled to earth through a large resistor. The internal low voltage rails, with respect to signal ground are: 3.3 V, +15V, -15V. These could be generated either via separate AC/DC modules, or via separated DC/DC modules after a single AC/DC converter. Is there a preference here, with respect to EMC ? All rails will be thoroughly filtered with common-mode noise being shunted away from signal ground into earth ground.

The circuit itself involves a fair amount of analog signal processing for mostly the audio frequency range using the +/- 15 V rails.

The digital and mixed signal parts are based around a Zynq-based system-on-a-module. I trust that this module is designed by its manufacturer to work well in terms of EMC. Specifically, we will use an sbrio from National Instruments now, but it could be any similar part from another company in the future.

The ground of the SoM is bolted to the signal ground of the mainboard. We adhere to good design practices for digital and mixed signal circuits: e.g.: stackup, return paths, placing/distancing of component groups, considering current loops of the supplies and circuits etc..

Connectors to the outside are mainly:

- mains inlet
- Ethernet jack, internally connected to the ethernet port on the SoM.
- some BNC connectors for analog signals. The shield is used for chassis ground, and only the inner conductor is used for the low frequency analog signals.

Specific questions I am unsure about:

1. The isolated signal ground needs some low impedance ESD path the earth ground. I have read that discrete capacitors are not efficient at usual ESD frequencies due to their inductance. Should I instead overlap an area of signal ground and chassis ground in the PCB stackup ?
2. Is the general device plan probably sound in terms of EMC/EMI or do you see some obvious problems ?
3. What kind of abuse is to be expected during the safety testing ? Mains power into the signal connectors ?
4. Do I need a mains filter in front of the AC/DC converter, if the AC/DC converter is CE approved ? If yes, are the inlets with integrated filters the way to go?
5. Is the isolated signal ground prudent and done in the right way? I reckon this will attract opinion based answers. From what I have read, the consensus seems to be: "No.. just short it to the chassis, unless you are designing a high precision analog circuit" Good. But what in the case of the precision analog circuit. How to do it in this case ?

**EDIT:**

I have been thinking more about (5.) myself. The usual reasoning is that you don't want spread-out low-frequency return current in the ground plane as the HF currents in the ground plane supposedly affect the signal level of the LF signal. The problem is that I can't really understand this argument and so I am beginning to lean towards just anyway using a low industance short to Chassis Ground for the Signal Ground planes.

a) high frequency current from earth has no reason to even enter the board

b) high frequency digital currents form ICs on the signal GND plane are inevitably there and pose no threat if they are placed far away.

c) HF noise entering the signals through the ground return is out-of-band and can be RC filtered. The C will make the ground noise common between the GND and the signal.

d) in especially demanding circumstances, a dedicated GND return trace can be routed for the analog signals.

e) having a short between signal ground and chassis somehow partially relieves my inner EMC concerns.

Best regards and many thanks in advance.

Comment: No matter what good advice you get and how good you implement that advice, you should still understand that there is no magic bullet to obtaining conformity to EMC. You should budget for failures to comply, rework and retesting.

Comment: Andy, I do understand that there are many pitfalls in the circuit design that can lead to an EMC failure.. Still I can do my best to increase the chance of passing. If we fail, well such is life. I also understand that it is impossible to rate the EMC of the actual circuit on the mainboard as I didnt give any details about it. That is because, I want to keep the question focused on those parts of the design, where we couldnt reach consensus, hence the 5 questions at the end.

Comment: There is a saying: CE + CE != CE. Basically you can get a handful CE conformant devices, put them in a box but not be CE conformant. CE is a number of standards and there are criteria that determine what level etc you’re expected to comply with. You need to determine what criteria best describes your box. Then you can determine what EMC etc standards you need to comply with. You then compare these with what your power supply etc is conformant with and in what configuration. The learning curve is significant - find yourself a consultant.

Comment: 1. You determine what is acceptable. What can your device be expected to be exposed to?

Comment: Kartman, thanks for pointing out the various levels within the same standards. Will double check that. Consulting is something that we might indeed use.. depending on the level of confidence we can build based on the information that we can get from the test houses and also here.

Comment: Kartman, "You determine what is acceptable." was that comment aimed at question (3.) instead of (1.) ? I cant seem to understand its relation to (1.)

Comment: Both. I did type a better response but the system timed me out. With the mains input, there are standards that determine the tests involved. With your analog inputs, you determine what is acceptable for the application. If your spec says 5V max and is for lab use indoors, then testing with 240vac and lightning is unreasonable.

Comment: Is your Ethernet jack PCB mounted or do yo run flying leads from the connector to the PCB ?

Comment: Hilmar: The current design has an Ethernet feedthrough in the Chassis (an Ethernet Jack on both inside and outside) and another short Ethernet cable from that feedthrough to the Ethernet Jack on the SOM. SOM Ground is bolted to signal ground, but the feedthrough is in the Chassis Ground. The short Ethernet Cable will keep these grounds separate as far as i understand.

Comment: The feedthrough usually just passes the wires through. You Zynq board ethernet will have to survive the expected tests for ethernet unless you specify otherwise. The zynq board hopefully has specific grounding for the ethernet jack.

Comment: I would suggest a varistor between signal ground and case/protective earth to help with ESD protection. It won't interfere with isolation between GNDs in normal operation but will conduct ESD spikes from signal to protective GND. (I've used 18V varistors here)

Comment: Brian Drummond, thanks for that advice. Sure sounds plausible and I also see no reason that speaks against it. Is it a proven tactic ? Does a  MOV or a TVS Diode have less problems with its inductance than a capacitor ? Or is that whole story about the inductance being an issue nonsense ?

Comment: Inductance is a common problem when you’re talking fast, high energy pulses. Any inductance in the loop may cause flashovers or other unintended consequences. The tests have standardised waveforms so you can calculate the outcome.

Comment: @tobalt I take it you're dealing with an outside world that favors unbalanced/coaxial interconnect, hence the BNCs?

Comment: ThreephaseEel: yes the BNC format is common in the target application, which is in research. As it is still a low frequency device, the BNC format is mainly used for shielding and not for impedance controlled transmission.